# Butt problems on my character model

Tags: modeling

So long story short, I tried to create a character model I failed at awhile back, and I failed again.
I can't really nail down on what went wrong, so I am just gonna send you some pictures of my model's butt.

[image]

This first image is with a subdivision surface modifier.

[image]

This second one is without.

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Comment: It would be helpful to show wireframes/edit mode picks so we can actually see your topology.

Comment: Check if you have internal faces in the model.

Comment: Its better you attach the blend file for detail investigation for your answer. Attach your file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but for me it looks like some of the faces are not split where they should be. On the low poly model it looks like when you are going from the lower back to the butt that the first face ( the one that is on the screenshot "over the red line") is not split in two verticaly. And also the face three below that. I cannot clearly see due to the perspective.

Optionally I could imagine that you maybe have 2 vertecies over each other so try and remove doubles, but I guess you already did that.
Hope that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately , the lower torso is a complicated shape that cannot be made simply by just manipulating a cube or it's cuts ,professional 3d creators use other methods all together , one method I use is just adding a plane and  a lattice to give it the shape it needs, because with a lattice you can be very flexible , and once that is done I just extrude the rest of the torso and the legs.
It is more anatomically correct (i'm speaking as an artist) to view the upper leg as a part of the lower torso rather than a separate piece , it's hard and tedious at the beginning to use the lattice to give the overall shape but after  a few tries it gets easier.
No wonder you will find very few clips about this matter because yes the lower torso HAS a difficult topology .